# How to preserve newlines in argparse version output while letting argparse auto-format/wrap the remaining help message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I wrote the following code.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version',
                    version='%(prog)s 1.0\nCopyright (c) 2016 Lone Learner')
parser.parse_args()
```

This produces the following output.

```
$ python foo.py --version
foo.py 1.0 Copyright (c) 2016 Lone Learner
```

You can see that the newline is lost. I wanted the copyright notice to appear on the next line.

How can I preserve the new lines in the version output message?

I still want argparse to compute how the output of `python foo.py -h` should be laid out with all the auto-wrapping it does. But I want the version output to be a multiline output with the newlines intact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RawTextHelpFormatter` will turn off the automatic wrapping, allowing your explicit `\n` to appear.  But it will affect all the `help` lines.  There's no way of picking and choosing.  Either accept the default wrapping, or put explicit newlines in all of your help lines.

You are getting to a level of pickiness about the help format that you need to study the `HelpFormatter` code for yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at `HelpFormatter` and found the following in its docstring: "Only the name of this class is considered a public API. All the methods provided by the class are considered an implementation detail." So I figured it is not a good idea to rely on the implementation of `HelpFormatter` if I want to guarantee that my code would continue to run well with future versions of Python. I guess I have to either accept the limitations of `argparse` and work within it, or handle `sys.argv` on my own.

Comment: Don't worry too much about that disclaimer.  If you need/want to write your own formatter subclass, do so.  Five years from now when a rewrite of the main class enters production, you can tweak your subclass if needed.  In the mean time your code will perform as you want.

Answer (score 3):

There's also [`argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#formatter-class).

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=True,
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    description="""an
already-wrapped
description
string""")
```

It leaves the `description` and `epilog` alone, and wraps only argument help strings.  The OP wanted the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be best off using a custom `argparse.Action` for this.

```
import argparse
import os
import sys

class MultilineVersionAction(argparse.Action):
    verbose_version = '1.0\nCopyright (c) 2016 Lone Learner'

    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=None, **kwargs):
        if nargs is not None:
            raise ValueError('nargs not allowed')
        # this is how argparse initialises `prog` by default
        self.prog = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
        super(MultilineVersionAction, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, nargs=0, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        parser.exit(message='{} {}\n'.format(self.prog, self.verbose_version))

# ...

    self.parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action=MultilineVersionAction)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use `action='version'`. The same pattern can be repeated for `-h`.

```
import os
import sys
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.version:
    prog = os.path.basename(__file__)
    print('{} 1.0\nCopyright (c) 2016 Lone Learner'.format(prog))
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with Hamish that you're best off using a custom Action, it's possible to leverage more of the `argparse` machinery, and to integrate more fully with it as well. For example:

```py
import argparse
import sys

__version__ = 1.0
__copyright__ = "Copyright Nobody <nobody@example.com>"

class _MyVersionAction(argparse._VersionAction):
    """Customized _VersionAction with RawDescription-formatted output."""
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        version = self.version
        if version is None:           # I have no idea why this is here¹
            version = parser.version  # ← (no such thing)
        formatter = argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter(
            prog=parser.prog)
        formatter.add_text(version)
        parser._print_message(formatter.format_help(), sys.stdout)
        parser.exit()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.register('action', 'my_version', _MyVersionAction)

parser.add_argument(
    '-V', '--version', action='my_version',
    version=f"%(prog)s {__version__}\n{__copyright__}")
parser.parse_args()
```

This `_MyVersionAction` class subclasses `argparse._VersionAction`, and is 90% a direct copy-paste of its code, warts and all.¹ (It doesn't even define an `__init__`, just inherits the parent's.)

But it makes a minimal adjustment to the `__call__` method, forcing its formatter to be `argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter`. The original code looked up the parser-wide one with `parser._get_formatter()`, but we don't want that here.

Then, after we create the parser instance, we register the action string `'my_version'` for `_MyVersionAction` so it can be used in `add_argument(..., action='my_version')` like any other action.

That allows you to, for example, use `%(prog)s` in the version string, or consume other data from the parser instance. It's also possible to reuse `action='my_version'` in multiple programs, because the version string isn't hardcoded. You just pass it to `add_argument()` like always.

##### Output

```
$ python3 /tmp/argtest.py --help
usage: argtest.py [-h] [-V]

options:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -V, --version  show program's version number and exit

$ python3 /tmp/argtest.py --version
argtest.py 1.0
Copyright Nobody <nobody@example.com>
```

##### Notes

1. Like the comment says, I have no idea why the action tries to get `parser.version` if `self.version` isn't set — there's no supported API for setting a `version` attribute on the `parser` object. You'd have to forcibly set it by hand, with `parser.version = X.Y`. I suspect that check is just code-cruft carried forward from an older version, or even from the `optparse` days.